# Выборка данных из связанных таблиц Laravel

Tags: laravel

Имеются две таблицы: users и articles. Они связаны между собой отношением один ко многим, т.е. у одного пользователя имеется несколько статей. 
Таблица users содержит поля id и name и др.
Таблица articles содержит поле author_id и др.

Класс User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function article() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article', 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

Класс Article:

```
class Article extends Model
    {
    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
    }

}
```

Шаблон blade:

```
    @foreach($articles as $k=>$article)
      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{!! $article->title!!}</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ $article->published_start }}  by {{ name }}</p>
        {!! $article->text !!}
      </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
    @endforeach
```

Необходимо вывести имя автора статьи, т.е. создать запрос который берет поле name из таблицы users.

Спустя время сделал выборку через join, но это больше похоже на костыль:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
        ->join('users', 'articles.author_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('title', 'published_start', 'name', 'text')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть модели и там прописаны реляции то и выводите данные с модели, а не через фасад `DB`, в вашем случае нужно было сделать так:

```
@foreach($articles as $k=>$article)
  <div class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{!! $article->title!!}</h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ $article->published_start }}  by {{ $article->user->name }}</p>
    {!! $article->text !!}
  </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
@endforeach
```